# How to use element-wise multiply between matrix and vector in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Below is my input:

```
a = np.array([[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]])
b = np.array([2,3,4])
```

I want to use a multiply b by column:

```
result = np.array([[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]])
```

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transpose -> broadcast -> transpose:

```
>>> (a.T * b).T
array([[2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 4]])
```

Comment: I don't think broadcast is being used here?

Comment: @krishna `b` is broadcasted along the rows of `a.T` for element-wise multiplication (if I have my terminology right).

Comment: as you say, I need to make sure a's column count is equal to b's elements count